# Sequentially reduce List<Mono<Boolean>> to single Mono<Boolean>, and abort processing if any return false

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have a list of tasks that are meant to be executed sequentially, returning `true` if the task succeeded, or `false` if it failed (non-exceptionally - there is a third case where it encountered some sort of exception, which should also abort processing, but I want to treat that as a distinct third case).

These tasks are represented as a list of `Mono<Boolean>` instances. There could be any number of them. From this list, I want to produce a `Mono<Boolean>` that has the following characteristics:

- It executes each task sequentially.
- If any task in the list returns `false` or encounters an exception, it should abort processing of any further tasks.
- It returns `true` if all tasks succeeded; `false` if any task failed non-exceptionally; it should emit an error if any tasks encountered an exception.

Here is an example list of 3 tasks - the first one succeeds, and the second one fails - so I don't want the third one to run:

```java
Mono<Boolean> task1 = Mono.create(sink -> {
    try {
        System.out.println("Executing task 1...");

        // Simulate some work being done
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        System.out.println("Finished executing task 1.");

        // This task is successful, return true
        sink.success(true);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        sink.error(e);
    }
});

Mono<Boolean> task2 = Mono.create(sink -> {
    try {
        System.out.println("Executing task 2...");

        // Simulate some work being done
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        System.out.println("Finished executing task 2.");

        // This task is NOT successful, return false
        sink.success(false);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        sink.error(e);
    }
});

Mono<Boolean> task3 = Mono.create(sink -> {
    try {
        System.out.println("Executing task 3...");

        // Simulate some work being done
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        System.out.println("Finished executing task 3.");

        // This task is successful, return true
        sink.success(true);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        sink.error(e);
    }
});

List<Mono<Boolean>> tasks = Arrays.asList(task1, task2, task3);
```

My first thought was to convert the list of `Mono`s to a `Flux`, and then use [`Flux#reduce`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#reduce-A-java.util.function.BiFunction-):

```java
Mono<Boolean> process = Flux.concat(tasks)
    .reduce(true, (accum, value) -> accum && value);

process.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

This correctly produces `false`, which indicates that one of the steps in the process did not succeed (step 2). However, given the output, it is clear that task 3 is still being executed, which is not correct:

```
Executing task 1...
Finished executing task 1.
Executing task 2...
Finished executing task 2.
Executing task 3...
Finished executing task 3.
false
```

I can get the desired behavior if I go back to the synchronous world and use [`Mono#block`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#block--), but this doesn't feel very idiomatic:

```java
Mono<Boolean> process = Mono.create(sink -> {
    Boolean result = true;

    for (Mono<Boolean> task: tasks) {
        result = task.block();

        if (!result) {
            break;
        }
    }

    sink.success(result);
});

process.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Is there a better way to do this using the built-in operators like `reduce`, `map`, `flatMap`, etc.?

Comment: Do you control the publishing side?  If so, given your requirements I think you'd be better off setting aside reactive programming here and instead just use a simple for-loop that directly executes the tasks sequentially.  Of course, if you are forced to consume reactively, then you'll have to find a reactive solution (and I'm afraid I'm not enough of an expert to help with that)

Comment: Can you reduce your list over `Mono::then` (potentially composed with `filter`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `takeUntil` to stop processing based on given condition:

```java
Mono<Boolean> process = Flux.concat(tasks)
    .takeUntil(x -> !x)
    .reduce(true, (accum, value) -> accum && value);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that is to sink an error if task was unsuccessful:

```
Mono<Boolean> task2 = Mono.create(sink -> {
    try {
        //...   
        // This task is NOT successful
        sink.error(new FailedTaskException());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        sink.error(e);
    }
});
```

And then use `.onErrorResume` operator to recover:

```
List<Mono<Boolean>> tasks = Arrays.asList(task1, task2, task3);
    Mono<Boolean> process = Flux.concat(tasks)
            .onErrorResume(FailedTaskException.class, (t) ->  Mono.just(false))
            .reduce(true, (accum, value) -> accum && value);
```